# How to solve this security vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, eslint

I'm getting below security vulnerability issue in **Gitlab** report:

Information I have:
`Improper Limitation of a Pathname to a Restricted Directory ('Path Traversal')`

Description:

`A variable is present in the filename argument of fs calls, this might allow an attacker to access anything on your system.`

Code:

```
const sanitizedPath = decodeURIComponent(IMPORTED_DOCUMENTATION_URL);
window.open(sanitizedPath, "_blank", "noopener");
```

Rule: eslint.detect-non-literal-fs-filename

Identifier: CWE-22 https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/22.html

How can I avoid this vulnerability?

Comment: This looks like a false positive. There is no actual server-side file system operation going on here, all this value is used for, is opening a specified URL in a popup window on the client. Path traversal is not a real issue here, I'd say - going up via `../` does not allow access to anything outside of the web root folder, and any change of a path below the web root, does not expose anything that would not have been accessible via the _direct_ path to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, can we make any modifications to the code to avoid that vulnerability form the Gitlab report?

Comment: I don't know how exactly that report works, what specifically it looks for, or whether it even tries to execute code or anything like that, so I could not tell you that. Perhaps it can be "soothed" by implementing some input validation, as explained in the advisory (_'If feasible, only allow a single "." character in the filename to avoid weaknesses such as CWE-23, and exclude directory separators such as "/" to avoid CWE-36.'_ - the part excluding directory separators might not be applicable, if you need to pass a full path, and not only the last segment.)

Comment: Looking at the [code for this linting rule](https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/rules/detect-non-literal-fs-filename.js) I'm struggling to understand how it relates to the code that you quoted. Are you sure that you are looking at the right part of your code?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure that vulnerability pointing to window.open line of code.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix:

I directly added URL string as first param to window.open function instead of importing from another file.

```
window.open("URL to open on new tab", "_blank", "noopener");
```